# use expect to automate the piped command

Tags: bash, automation, automated-tests, expect

I want to automate a piped command `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@host 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'` in `expect`. When using `spawn` command to execute the command,

```
spawn cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh root@host 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
```

it throws error msg,

```
cat |: No such file or directory
cat ssh: No such file or directory
...
```

How should I spawn the piped commands?

Comment: You probably need to escape the `|` with a backslash (`\|`).  Also, why not just use `ssh-copy-id`?

Comment: @SeanBright: I think you have that backward. The problem is that the OP *wants* the `|` to be treated as special, and `expect`/`spawn` doesn't support that.

Comment: by adding backslash, it does not work. @ruakh is there any workaround for this? like reorganising shell command.

Answer (score 5):

Because you want to technically execute multiple shell commands in one hit (and spawn doesn't handle the piped I/O), you need to encapsulate them in a script then use spawn to execute the script.

The script you want already exists as ssh-copy-id, however if you want a trimmed down version you can create a script file on the fly then pass that into expect spawn:

```
cat > /tmp/sshkeycopy.sh <<MYEOF
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@host 'mkdir -p -m 600 ~/.ssh; cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
MYEOF

chmod u+x /tmp/sshkeycopy.sh

expect -c "
spawn /tmp/sshkeycopy.sh
expect { ... }"
```

With this bash example, the shell will handle the pipe as expected and just throw the password prompt out for expect to handle.

Answer (score 3):

Does `spawn` handle input redirection?

```
spawn ssh root@host "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys" < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Input redirection would be preferred over using `cat` with a single file if you weren't using `expect`.

Edit: use double quotes around `cat` command, instead of single quote (which does not work, as tested)

Comment: this works! can you explain a bit what's the difference btwn input redirection and pipeline with cat?

Comment: In a pipe, there are two processes, with the output of the first connected to the input of the second. With redirction, there is a single process, and bash changes its input from the terminal (or whatever the default input is) to the file before running the process.

Comment: there is one problem though, ssh interprete ``< ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`` as in remote node, not locally. is there a way to specify that being local?

Comment: Hmm. It appears that `spawn` is executing the command directly, not passing it to a shell to be processed. This answer is obviously not useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
spawn bash -c "cat MEH | ssh root@host 'cat >>HMM' "
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This has been tested and works on Linux

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set DOMAIN www.somedomain.tld
set TARFILE "[exec bash -c "echo $DOMAIN | cut -d'.' -f 1"].cert.tar"
puts "$TARFILE\r"
```